# I am not executing my push/pop methods correctly, can someone help me out?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

so I am working on a calculator application and my code is currently not executing properly. I know what is wrong, but I am not sure how to go about fixing it. Currently, I have my ViewController.m with the current code when I press the addition button:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CalcLogic.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *display;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastOperation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CalcLogic* logic;

@end

@implementation ViewController
double result = 0;
//Last operation entered into the calculator
NSString* lastEntered;
@synthesize logic;

-(IBAction)numPressed:(UIButton *)sender{
    BOOL hasBeenCleared = [self.lastOperation.text isEqualToString:@"Clear"];

    if ([self.display.text isEqualToString:@"0."]) {
        self.display.text = sender.currentTitle;;
        self.lastOperation.text = sender.currentTitle;;
        [self.logic pushNumber:[sender.currentTitle doubleValue]];
    }
    else{
        self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:sender.currentTitle];
        if (self.lastOperation.text.length > 1 && hasBeenCleared != TRUE) {
            self.lastOperation.text = [self.lastOperation.text stringByAppendingString:sender.currentTitle];
        }
        else {
            self.lastOperation.text = sender.currentTitle;
        }
        [self.logic pushNumber:[sender.currentTitle doubleValue]];
    }
}

-(IBAction)clearPressed:(UIButton *)sender{
    self.display.text = @"0.";
    self.lastOperation.text = @"Clear";
    [self.logic clearStack];
    result = 0;
}

-(IBAction)operation:(UIButton *)sender{
    [logic pushOperation:sender.currentTitle];
    NSString* resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result];
    self.display.text = resultString;
    if ([self.lastOperation.text isEqualToString:@"Clear"]) {
        self.lastOperation.text = @"";
        self.lastOperation.text = [self.lastOperation.text stringByAppendingString:sender.currentTitle];
    }
    else{
        self.lastOperation.text = [self.lastOperation.text stringByAppendingString:sender.currentTitle];
    }
}

-(IBAction)equalHit:(UIButton *)sender{
    result = [self.logic performOperation];
    self.display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result];

}
```

My issue is with pushing and popping objects to the arrays. The arrays are located in `logic`, and I am trying to push numbers to one of two arrays in `logic`, and the operators to another array in object. However, I must be doing something wrong because nothing is being pushed when I check in the console (as far as I can tell). I am still new to this language and am coming from a Java packground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't alloc/init `logic` anywhere in your code. You need this line, probably in `viewDidLoad` or some other initialization function:

```
logic = [[CalcLogic alloc] init];
```

Comment: Since it is defined as a public property, perhaps it is assigned by an outside class. Otherwise there is no need for a public property.

Comment: @rmaddy There's plenty of uses for a public property.  As it stands, his code does not demonstrate that the object is being initialized, so that is my first assumption as to why it wouldnt work, without further implementation details of the `CalcLogic` class

Comment: if you use self.logic in code then initialize it with self like 
    self.logic=[[CalcLogic alloc] init];

Comment: @DanF My comment was really a hint to Dave. A public read/write property should only be used if outside classes need to both get and set the value. IF outside classes are supposed to just read the property then make it readonly. Otherwise it should be a private property defined in the .m file. When I see public properties I expect their use to be public, not private. Anyway, I agree that your answer is most likely the problem.

Comment: Oh, silly me! You are right, I didn't initialize it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Dave It is easy to forget, especially if you come from pretty much any other programming language that will throw errors or exceptions when you attempt to invoke methods on null(or nil in obj-c's case) objects